# Express Middleware seems to not enter the next route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following middleware on Express.js

```
module.exports = function(req,res,next) {
  if(!req.session.id){
    res.redirect("/login");
  } else {
    next();
  }
};
```

I do not know why, but the middleware seems to be hanged if I attach files to the request, and do not enter the desire route or it does not even throws a 404 error code

Comment: Can you explain what the req.get('header') should do ? Are you targeting a certain key of the header ?

Comment: Actually it is just a key/value thing, it's just a tweak more related on the origin of the call

Comment: Your if statement at the beginning is unnecessary. Remove all unused code. Console.log where the if is going to - i would say the redirect is not working rather than the next callback.

Comment: I edited my question to reflect on what is going on right now